# How to make UIButton move with UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have a `UIScrollView` menu that moves above and below the viewport via the activation of a `UIButton`. The issue is that the button only stays in one place when I press it to make the `UIScrollView` menu move up and down. I want the `UIButton` to say **above** the `UIScrollView` menu when it is activated. Here's what it looks like, the "open" is the `UIButton`:

[image]

Here are the animation codes from the `viewcontroller.m` for the `UIScrollView` and `UIButton`.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize scrollView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    draw1 = 0;
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 300, 480, 55);
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(480, 55)];

    openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(220, 270, 60, 30);
}

- (IBAction)OpenMenu:(id)sender {
    if (draw1 ==0) {
        draw1 = 1;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              delay:0.0
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{
                             scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 1000, 568, 200);
                             openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(220, 200, 60, 30);
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             NSLog(@"Done!");
                         }];
    } else {
        draw1 = 0;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              delay:0.0
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{
                             scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 300, 568, 200);
                             openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(220, 270, 60, 30);
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             NSLog(@"Done!");
                         }];
    }
}
```

I want the "open" button to be above the green `UIScrollView` (not on top of it), how do I do this?

Comment: Are you creating openMenu from user interface? if yes make sure openMenu is connected with IBOutlet

Comment: @C_X It is connected with the IBoutlet.

Comment: Arr you adding some constraint, updating frame in viewDidLayoutSubviews.... ?

Comment: No, that is not part of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay change `openMenu.frame = <frame>` to `openMenu.layer.frame = <frame>`

Your code should be like this
set initial frame add this method

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    draw1 = 1;
    openMenu.layer.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.center.x - 30, self.view.frame.size.height - 80, 60, 30);
}

 - (IBAction)OpenMenu:(id)sender {
    if (draw1 ==0) {
        draw1 = 1;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              delay:0.0
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{
                             scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 1000, 568, 200);
                             openMenu.layer.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.center.x - 30, self.view.frame.size.height - 80, 60, 30);
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             NSLog(@"Done!");
                         }];
    } else {
        draw1 = 0;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              delay:0.0
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{
                             scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 300, 568, 200);
                             openMenu.layer.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.center.x - 30, 270, 60, 30);
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             NSLog(@"Done!");
                         }];
    }
}
```

Comment: inside animations block, i updated answer with your code

Comment: This is what happens, when I press the button, it moves to the left near the top. When I press it again, the button moves down and the menu comes up. When I press it one last time, the button goes back to the left near the top. Looks like this - http://s2.postimg.org/sb5vzhpqh/unnamed_2.png

Comment: I got two errors. The first one - Propert 'draw' not found on object of type 'ViewController*' on this line -     self.draw = 1;

Comment: this is your draw1 you can change it I think

Comment: The second one says - Property 'openMenu' not found on object of type'ViewController'*: did you mean to access instance variable 'openMenu'?

Comment: so you can remove self. it will work, Actually I did it you can use updated code

Comment: Happy iOS programming dude